# Software update error: Apt folder is no longer accessible, but is on a USB drive - need to move it back

Tags: apt, package-management, usb-drive, restore

Primary environment: Windows 10 64 Pro, Ubuntu 18.04 hosted on VMware Workstation:

My system console could not be accessed after exceeding the allocated memory size.  I increased the size, but was still unable to access the main console, but had access via **ctrl-alt F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6** to Terminal.  There I identified some files that could be deleted and (unfortunately) also deleted the Deb files.  Also I issued the following command:
**sudo mv -i /var/cache/apt /media/usb** .
After this command the apt directory was on my USB drive.
I think my other problems(*) of system update will be resolved if I can move it back, but the syntax to do it to /var/cache/ is not clear to me, since this is a system folder. (the apt directory still resides on the USB drive).

(*)Now I have full access to Ubuntu, but updates are not working.  I get the following message:
"Archives directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing. - Acquire (2:No such file or directory)"
My intent now is to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, but it is not possible until updates are installed.

Your support is most welcome!
Dick

Comment: Try adding a link to the new location: sudo ln -s /media/usr/apt /var/cache/apt   That might be enough, and meets your intention of saving space.

Comment: Hello ubfan1,  First, thank you for that input - actually I think it worked, as after using that syntax I was able to update the system.  After doing so, I implemented the update to 20.04, which I suspect was successful, as I was able to get into the system after all of the downloads, updates, etc.  Unfortunately, Murphy took over afterwards, and the 3.0 TB Seagate drive on which I house the VM died!  Replace the drive and start again.  Recovery unlikely - I've researched solutions, but short of a professional replacing some diodes, it is unlikely I'll ever see that version of Ubuntu again. :(